# How to close pages like this without killing firefox?

Tags: firefox, web, popups, advertisements

Whenever I'm browsing porn, there are eventually advertisements that show [this](http://w75g63.com) (safe for work) page (**WARNING: you might not be able to close it**).

The page claims you did something illegal, and threatens you, saying you need to pay money to avoid going to jail. Or something like that.

How can I close pages like this? I've had this issue in multiple versions of Firefox. Right now I'm on 26.0. How can I close it without simply killing the Firefox process?

---

Note: The plugins Adblock or NoScript might prevent this, but I don't use those. I would like to be able to close a page without downloading a separate plugin for it.

Comment: What about pressing Esc to stop loading the page, and then Ctrl+W to close it?

Comment: It seems to be a phishing page (as of now), and should be blocked by default in Firefox. Is [Block reported web forgeries](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/security-and-passwords-settings) manually disabled in Tools (Alt + T) > Options > Security. See also [Malware, and Phishing protection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-does-phishing-and-malware-protection-work).

Comment: @vWil: I don't use the phishing filter, and even if I did, that would not fix my problem.

Comment: @and31415: Yes that would work, but I cannot anticipate when I'm going to get a page like this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what OS you are on and what you have tried already, on Windows you might want to try Task Manager. On OSX you can try to force quit by right clicking or control clicking on the apps icon. I'm guessing you have already tried that so possibly [this question](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959815) on mozilla could help you?

Comment: I know you can kill the browser. I want to close just the tab (not kill the whole browser). By the way, I've come across this problem on both Windows and Linux.